# view-only dashboard in jira 5.2

Tags: jira, dashboard

The goal we'd like to achieve is allowing a customer to view a read-only dashboard which would display the status of only that customer's issue(s). This could be a default dashboard assigned to/associated with a particular group. Is there a way to configure a dashboard to accomplish that?
Thanks in advance for whatever help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

The edit permission is controlled by the permission scheme used by a project that issues are in. So to make the displayed issues read-only you'll need to decide which JIRA projects the issues come from and change the permission scheme for all those projects.

Answer (score 0):

To create a read-only dashboard, you must edit the workflow (Project/Administration/Workflows/Scheme:Edit) in the (Flash-based) Workflow Editor.

I suggest that you start by cloning the default workflow and making changes to the clone (rather than editing the default).

There will be items in a "Global Transitions" list. By default, all members of the "users" group will have the power to execute these transitions (even if you have altered your project's Permissions Scheme to prevent read-only users from creating issues or comments, for example).

1> Remove all of the items in the "Global Transitions" list

There will be items in a "Statuses" list. The "Resolved" status is an implicit part of the "Done" global transition, so it needs to be added to the workflow.

2> Drag the "Resolved" item from the "Statuses" list to the workflow.

Creating a transition involves selecting one of the 3 buttons, grouped with the mouse-pointer button, on the upper left corner of the Workflow Editor.

3> Select a transition type (Straight Line, Polygonal Line, Bezier Line) using the above buttons.

4> Click (and release) on the starting point of the transition (for example, "In Progress"). An arrow will appear under the mouse pointer.

5> Click  (and release) on the destination point of the transition (for example, "Done"). You will be prompted to give the transition a name (the text that you enter for this name will appear on a button, in classic issue views, that performs the transition), such as: "ChangeToDone".

The new transition is now available to everyone, unless you lock it down with some conditions:

6> Click on the gear-like button (to the right of the transition name) and select "View Conditions".

7> Click on "Add a new condition to restrict when this transition can be performed".

8> Select a condition (such as "Only Assignee Condition"), scroll to the bottom of the list, and click the "Add" button.

Now you should have a workflow transition that can only be performed by users who meet the required conditions.

Repeat the above steps to craft conditional transitions between all of the statuses that you use in your project.

To use your new workflow scheme with your project, click the "Switch Scheme" button (Project/Administration/Workflows/Scheme) and then click the "Associate" button.

Once the association process is finished, sign-in as a user that does not satisfy any of the transition conditions. You should be unable to perform transitions when signed-in as this user.